# Join 2 key value pair option objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-dialog

How can I merge the 2 key-value pairs defaultDialogSetup and setupArray?

```
var defaultDialogSetup = { modal: true, show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' };

var setupArray = {
                open: function (e) { $(this).load($(link).attr('href')); },
                title: link.innerHTML,               
                width: 300,
                height: 250,
                buttons:
                {
                    "OK": function () { createTemplate($(this), $('form', this)); },
                    "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                }
            };

$dialog.dialog(setupArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

use `jQuery.extend()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first
>   object.

```
setupArray = $.extend(defaultDialogSetup, setupArray);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I just looked for javascript not jquery and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is UnderscoreJS extend()

http://underscorejs.org/#extend

> Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override properties of the same name in previous arguments.

The syntax is very similar to the jQuery method:

> setupArray = _.extend(defaultDialogSetup, setupArray);